# Update twilio flex webchat config

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, twilio, twilio-flex

How can we update twilio config? Don't mind if we have to restart engagement.
Scenario is pre-login and post-login. I want to have `preEngagementConfig` if the user is not logged in while it should be removed after login and `context` should be introduced.
Tried setting `FlexWebChat.defaultConfiguration.preEngagementConfig = null;` didn't work;

Also tried removing the node where ReactDOM is rendering the app, and re-initialize the app, but getting error `default store already exists`.

I think it is a valid scenario and Twilio should provide API out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

To restart engagement you could use `FlexWebChat.Actions.invokeAction('RestartEngagement')`. It works using the `import * as FlexWebChat from '@twilio/flex-webchat-ui'` in react flex-webchat-ui.